# resignFirstResponder expected identifier

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I want to hide keyboard if user press return key! 
here .h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>;


@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *testItHere;

@end
```

and .m

```
    @implementation ViewController
@synthesize testItHere;
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField;
{
    [self.testItHere.resignFirstResponder]
    return YES
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [self updateTestKeyboard:self.interfaceOrientation];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

self.testItHere.delegate=self;
}
```

But error says:expected identifier, what is wrong with this code?

Comment: You are missing the semicolon at the end. Use this statement instead `[textField resignFirstResponder];`.

Comment: still same error, and your suggested statement not working too.

Comment: In `Objective-C` semicolons are mandatory to end a statement. You are missing one after `return YES` too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the dot:

```
[self.testItHere resignFirstResponder];
```

Answer (score -2):

Remove dot and you call `textFieldShouldReturn` for hide keyboard when return key is pressed.

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
 {
     [self.testItHere resignFirstResponder];
     return YES;
 }
```